# Files are "open" in a List<File> and get out of memory

Tags: java, file, out-of-memory

I met a problem in doing followed stuff with Java:

1. Create a .xls file and write some content in it on server.
2. Store this file into a List.
3. Repeat step 1 and 2 thousands times and get a List with thousands of .xls files in it.
4. Export the Files into a .zip archive.

My problem is seems that the created files are all "open" and it will be out of memory. Actually each file is only about 37 kb and number of file is only about 2000. I think it's not too much but it failed every time. So anyone has some idea about this problem? Thank you so much!

Comment: You should provide the actual error you got and a representative sample of code.

Comment: 37k * 2000 = 74 megabytes.  That's not "a lot" but it's definitely a lot of memory to be holding at one time.  Your app needs memory itself to run.  How are the memory parameters of this app configured?  Did you give the app at least a couple of gigabytes to run?

Comment: You didn't post an actual error message, and I suspect you're out of file handles, not memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're going about the process the wrong way. A ZIP file isn't built by reading every file into memory, compressing it, then writing the output. Instead, it's written one file at at time, with only the *directory listing* stored in memory. In pseudo-code, that means you're doing this:

```
Create Zip Memory Directory
Open Zip File Handle
For Each File In Directory
    Open File In Read Mode
    Compress File
    Write Headers and File To Zip File
    Store Info About File in Zip Memory Directory
    Close File
End For
Write Zip Memory Directory to Zip File
Close Zip File Handle
```

This means you only need as much memory as required for a single file to compress, and you only have two files open at any given time. This is partly because most systems have a limited amount of space ("handles") to track open files with, so depending on the language/OS/whatever, you may actually be exhausting your platform's limits of file handles per thread/process/entire system. Similarly, decompression is also usually implemented one file at a time.

In Java, you'd just as likely actually be using a Zip utility class, reading each file, compressing it to a place in memory, then closing that file, and looping for the remaining files; at the end of the entire process, you save the Zip file to disk.

See [ZipOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html) for one such class that you could use. In practice, it works by accepting an OutputStream (created by opening a file in write mode), and then calling putNextEntry, write, closeEntry, in a loop, and finally calling close() to flush the file to disk.